# Cannot find module 'express' on nodejs.log

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I have a react and nodejs project on the host 'O2Switch'.
My React seems to work fine, but there is a whitepage on my url https://www.desmettre-maxime-canin.com/ because of my node not respond. On localhost, it's good.

In my nodejs.log file, i have the error "Cannot find module 'express' on nodejs.log"

How to fix this please ??? The module is correctly installed on my node_modules, good in package.json etc.
I tried a million time to re-install express in a million ways...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello first check again if you installed express via npm in **root** directory of your project.Some users had same problem and used this command and worked

```
npm install express --save
```

or install a specific express version

```
npm install express@4.18.1
```

Also try to remove node_modules and package.json file,clear npm cache ,maybe you did it many times and accidentaly you created errors.And after that try again to install npm depedencies

```
rm-rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm clean cache --force
npm init
```

Finally try to fix node_path environment variable,if your node_modules is in another directory

```
set NODE_PATH=your\directory\to\node_modules;%NODE_PATH%
```

I am not sure but installing many times express may caused this problem,you can check this by creating new project with clean install of npm packages.